# Doing a parallel read from a defined number of files

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, multiprocessing

For a school project, I have to make a program in which the user chooses from 1 to 10 text files. Then, the program must search into this files with multiprocessor parallelism ([Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) I assume) to find a word and get the correct line.

I thought of putting the read into a `Parallel.For` but I have to avoid different processes to read from the same file at the same time.

How can I tell my `Parallel.For` to do that?

Comment: If you are working on a single program, why would there be different processes?

Comment: why you think Parallel.For will read the same file twice?

Answer (score 4):

You're on the good path by using TPL, Tasks (and await async if you can use .net 4.5).

1. You can use one main thread to perform a reading by line.
2. You store lines in a collection
3. Then you can perform the pattern search operation using TPL.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the Thread class in .Net. Look at this tutorials from MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740(v=vs.71).aspx.

Basically you would run a thread for each file you need to read and then be able to know when each one of them are done processing its respective file.

EDIT: Though, I would recommend parrallelism only if you have very large files.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you write a wrapper class reading from files, and make sure you do not read the same file twice.